# TypeError: getDay is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used getDay method in my JavaScript code, but I am getting getDay is not a function.

Below is my js code,

```
var lsDate = document.getElementById('<%=txtAddDate.ClientID %>');
var loIsDate = new Date(lsDate.value);
if (loIsDate != 'Invalid Date') {
    alert(lsDate.getDay());
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle code : http://jsfiddle.net/C4hVd/

Am I missing something?

Comment: You surely mean `loIsDate.getDay()` ?

Answer (score 4):

it should be `loIsDate`

```
alert(loIsDate.getDay());
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C4hVd/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
var loIsDate = new Date(lsDate.value);
```

to

```
var loIsDate = new Date(lsDate);
```

and

```
alert(lsDate.getDay());
```

to

```
 alert(loIsDate.getDay());
```